# BEM: How to ensure the CSS value within a block overrides the property defined in another block?

Tags: css, sass, overriding, bem

I'm using BEM and am having problems getting properties from one block to override styles in another. I know some might suggest to add a modifier for .button, but there are cases where certain properties need to be applied to a single page, so isn't worth having to add a whole nother modifier.

Here's an example, just to show my issue:

```
.button {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Now, when I go add a padding-left, it's getting `padding-left: 0;` instead of the value I want to use that's defined under `.my-block`.

```
.my-block {
  &__button {
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}
```

What is the best way to ensure the `padding-left: 5px;` gets applied as opposed to `padding-left: 0;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you use mixes so that markup looks like this:

```
<button class="button my-block__button">
```

If that's the case you need to ensure the order in the bundle (.button's styling should always go before `.my-block__button`).

In [BEM Platform](https://en.bem.info/platform/) we use [deps system](https://en.bem.info/platform/deps/) which gives us that guarantee.